# Apps are unable to use files from another HDD after reboot

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

I have another HDD and few apps that use files from that HDD. For example, I store audio files there and listen to them using Clementine. Usually I add my audio files to the playlist but after any reboot I'm unable to listen to those unless I add them to the playlist once again, Clementine crashes with something about unable to locate files or something like that.

For the time I thought this is Clementine's issue but today I installed completely different app called Lutris and installed few things through it on my another HDD. It worked fine till reboot, after the reboot it was throwing yet another error about being unable to locate something but after I set the path manually through Nautilus it works fine again till another reboot

[image]

I don't know how to explain the problem any further but I start to believe that it loses "links" to the files or doesn't have an access to them on that HDD before I locate them manually in the current session

Comment: You're right, 18 wasn't clear enough. It's 18.04, I called it latest because I'm often getting ubuntu core updates and I always install them when it's suggested. The system is installed, not running it 'live'. I don't mount it myself it's like always mounted on boot for me. I'm not experienced enough with ubuntu just yet but all I'm able to tell that I'm able to find location of those files through `Nautilus -> Other locations`

Comment: @guiverc upd: I checked and it's mounted as `/dev/sda5` if this is what you meant. If i recall correctly it was mounted on Ubuntu installation when I created a partition from my second HDD for using it as a store

Comment: Have you created the directory mentioned in the error message? Read `man mkdir`.

Comment: @waltinator as I said I'm able to open that directory via Nautilus means it does exist

Comment: Then, it seems like the other HDD has not spun up, checked itself, announced itself to the computer, and been mounted, when you start `wine`.

Comment: Read `man mountpoint sleep` and wrap your `wine` invocation with `bash` script that first does 0.1 second sleeps until `mountpoint /media/zz/222...` says it's mounted.